# Scale loaded SVG and zoom in with snap svg

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

So basically what I need to do is to load an SVG with SNAP.svg and add an effect (zoom in) I understand that in order to achieve this I need to respect this :

- Load the SVG file
- Scale de SVG in (0 ?)
- Append this SVG
- Add a transform effect (with the suitable scale)

The problem is that I need to display this in a 650 width and 280 height size.

The SVG I'm loading, witch I'll name it 'map' is in 1920 width and 1080 height.

This is my code so far :

```
    <svg id="svg" width="650px" height="280px"></svg>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var s = Snap("#svg");

        var map = Snap.load("./src/map.svg", function (f) {
                        g = f.select("g");
                        var t = Snap.matrix().scale(0.35);
                        s.append(g);
                        g.group(g.selectAll("path")).transform(t);  
                    });
    </script>
```

It seems the scale instruction is working find but not the animation. 
Also, how I can center this loaded SVG not matter what scale it takes ?

Thank you !

**UPDATE :**

I managed to add some effects but I don't think the way I'm doing it it's the correct one :

```
            var carte = Snap.load("./src/carte.svg", function (f) {
                        g = f.select("g");
                        //var t = Snap.matrix().scale(0.35);
                        s.append(g);
                        //Set the map in first position
                        var firstScene = new Snap.Matrix();
                        firstScene.translate(300, 160);
                        firstScene.scale(0.05);

                        //Zoom effect
                        var secondScene = new Snap.Matrix();
                            secondScene.scale(2.0);
                            secondScene.translate(-850, -360);

                        //Move the matrix till desired point (not finish)
                        var threeScene = new Snap.Matrix();
                            threeScene.translate(-850, -360);

                        g.animate({ transform: firstScene }, 0, function() {g.animate ({ transform: secondScene}, 1500, mina.linear )});

                    });
```

It seems impossible to add a timer or more than two effects ?

Comment: Could you put it on a jsfiddle ? I'd probably just use Snaps transform strings, like transform('s0.35'), save a bit of code. There isn't any animation in your code ? You can also basically zoom in just via changing the viewBox on the svg (s) element if you want to zoom everything in.

Comment: I already using transform and it seems to work, but the problem is that I whant to add an animation and I can't find the way

Comment: You can just call a callback on the 2nd animate too to get a 3rd, but at that point you probably want to do something slightly different code wise. Here's a possible example of one route you could take http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-animateframe (if its useful I'll put the code as an answer)

Comment: It seems to be the correct way in order to add animations, I finally managed to make this work, you can post as an answer too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as an alternative if there are quite a few sequenced animations I may be tempted to write a function to handle an array of animations. It could look something like this...

```
function nextFrame ( el, frameArray,  whichFrame ) {
    if( whichFrame >= frameArray.length ) { return }
    el.animate( frameArray[ whichFrame ].animation, 
                frameArray[ whichFrame ].dur, 
                frameArray[ whichFrame ].easing, 
                nextFrame.bind( null, el, frameArray, whichFrame + 1 ) );
}

var block = s.rect(100, 100, 100, 100, 20, 20);
             .attr({ fill: "rgb(236, 240, 241)", stroke: "#1f2c39",
                     strokeWidth: 3, transform: 's1' });

var frames = [
    { animation: { transform: 's0.4,0.4,200,200' },         dur: 1000, easing: mina.bounce },
    { animation: { transform: 't-100,-80' },                dur: 1000, easing: mina.bounce },
    { animation: { transform: 's1.2,1.2,300,300t200,-100' },dur: 1000, easing: mina.bounce }
    ];

nextFrame( block, frames, 0 );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hkyLqtw/7/)

Comment: I found this is the best (cleaner) way for doing this, thank you again !

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine, but like lan said above, maybe his method it's better for doing animations

```
        var carte = Snap.load("./src/carte.svg", function (f) {
                        g = f.select("g");
                        //var t = Snap.matrix().scale(0.35);
                        s.append(g);
                        //Load the map
                        var firstScene = new Snap.Matrix();
                        firstScene.translate(295, 160);
                        firstScene.scale(0.04);

                        //Set scene 1
                        var secondScene = new Snap.Matrix();
                            secondScene.scale(0.4);
                            secondScene.translate(-300, -10);

                        //Set scene 2
                        var threeScene = new Snap.Matrix();
                            //threeScene.scale(0.5);
                            threeScene.translate(-825, -380);

                        //Set scene 3
                        var fourScene = new Snap.Matrix();
                            fourScene.scale(21.0);
                            fourScene.translate(-1164, -526);

                        var anim1 = function() {
                            g.animate({ transform: firstScene}, 0, anim2);
                        }
                        var anim2 = function() {
                            g.animate({ transform: secondScene}, 1500, mina.easing, anim3);
                        }
                        var anim3 = function() {
                            g.animate({ transform: threeScene}, 1000, mina.linear, anim4);

                        }
                        var anim4 = function() {
                            g.animate({ transform: fourScene}, 2000, mina.easing);

                        }

                        anim1();

                    });
```

Is the fact of adding several matrix a performance killer ? Or this is the way it should be done ?

Comment: I don't think there would be too much of a perfomance issue as long as there aren't multiple transformations all applying at once. You look to be doing these one after each other, which looks fine to me. As mentioned you could cut out all of the matrix code completely, and just having the transform string, but thats just personal preference really.

Comment: Yes I'm doing it one after each other, thank you for your help lan !

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to sequence animations, the most elegant way would be to use promises. For that all you would need is to wrap animate function in Q library or jQuery.Deferred. Here is the example I put together on jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/stsvilik/Lnhc77b2/

```
 function animate(obj, conf, duration, asing) {
     var def = Q.defer();
     obj.animate(conf, dur, easing, function(){
        def.resolve();
     });
     return def.promise;
 }
```